# Fatal exression error with my image background color

Tags: kotlin, error-handling, fatal-error

I'm following an old Kotlin course, and as their course is quite old, I don’t think they respond to Q&A any more.

My issue here is that the app works completely fine, but as soon as I implement that one background color method, it stops.

Here is the *fatal* error I get:

```
2019-11-21 11:46:14.035 31147-31147/com.example.smack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smack, PID: 31147
    java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:876)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1502)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2431)
        at com.example.smack.Services.UserDataService.returnAvatarColor(UserDataService.kt:35)
        at com.example.smack.Controller.MainActivity$userDataChangeReciever$1.onReceive(MainActivity.kt:72)
        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
        at androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The main focus is on `UserDataService.kt:35)` which is where I'm converting the colors from doubles to Int:

```
fun returnAvatarColor(components: String) : Int {
    val strippedColor = components.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "")

    var r = 0
    var g = 0
    var b = 0

    val scanner = Scanner(strippedColor)
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        r = (scanner.nextDouble() * 255).toInt()
        g = (scanner.nextDouble() * 255).toInt()
        b = (scanner.nextDouble() * 255).toInt()
    }
    return Color.rgb(r,g,b)
}
```

And after that the `(MainActivity.kt:72)` which is where I'm fetching the method in order to display it:

```
userImageNavHeader.setBackgroundColor(UserDataService.returnAvatarColor(UserDataService.avatarColor))
```

Whenever I run the app it works, but as soon as I try to create an avatar and fetch its `background color` it crashes, and if I delete the method it goes back to working perfectly fine.

Comment: What string is being passed to `returnAvatarColor()` that causes it to crash?  (I.e. what is `UserDataService.avatarColor`?)

Comment: @gidds its just an empty `var avatarColor = ""` that will get the value from the returnAvatarColor displaying the background color

Comment: The stack trace shows that one of your calls to `Scanner.nextDouble()` is failing, because the string it's scanning doesn't have a valid double at that point.  To see why, you need to know what string it's scanning — i.e. what `strippedColor` contains.  And that depends on the string passed _into_ `returnAvatarColor()` (as `components`).  Find that, and the problem will probably become clear.

Comment: the error is coming from `  g = (scanner.nextDouble() * 255).toInt()` or at least thats where it points  me towards but its literally done the same way as the r and the b so I dont get why theres an error... I also downloaded source code from the course to check if I had a difference in code but I didnt miss anything yet in the video theres no error while mine gives Fatal errors

Comment: managed to fix the issue, for some reason the val scanner was not working so i just removed it and now it finally works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by removing the

```
    val scanner = Scanner(strippedColor)
```

method and displaying it like this:

```
if (Scanner(strippedColor).hasNext()) {
    r = (Scanner(strippedColor).nextDouble() * 255).toInt()
    g = (Scanner(strippedColor).nextDouble() * 255).toInt()
    b = (Scanner(strippedColor).nextDouble() * 255).toInt()
}
```

Comment: That may run, but probably doesn't do what you want it to: it's setting all three variables to the _same_ value (taken from the start of the string).  To fix the problem properly, you'll need to see what value `strippedColor` actually _has_; then you'll be able to tell how best to parse it.

Comment: its working fine ive set the values here  `return Color.rgb(r,g,b)` and it doesnt randomize it picks exactly what i need